# Issue with auth_request proxy having IP rather than domain name for the upstream request

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, authentication

I am trying to reconfigure some stuff that I have setup with NGINX - php-fpm running in a Docker setup.  I am using the http_auth_request_module to get authorization for another script before proxying the a request to a backend server.

Previously, the auth_request was being proxied to https://127.0.0.1/auth.php, which would end up in the default host on the NGINX server, and if I put the scripts in there and returned status 200 vs. 403 all worked as expected.

Now, I actually want to proxy to a specific domain that is served up by the same NGINX server in Docker. (e.g. https://subdomain.domain.com/auth.php.

The issue that I am seeing is that the the upstream url has an IP address instead of a domain name.  e.g. subrequest: "/auth", upstream: "https://192.168.0.100:443/ProxyPassAuth" rather than subrequest: "/auth", upstream: "https://subdomain.domain.com/ProxyPassAuth".  It was probably always that way and 'worked' because I had the upstream scripts being served by the default host.

The location block for the auth_request /auth is like currently after adding some stuff in an effort to "fix" that.  It seems like NGINX resolves the host name and then substitutes the IP for the hostname.

```
location = /auth {

    internal;
    proxy_pass https://subdomain.domain.com/ProxyPassAuth.php;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host subdomain.domain.com; 
    proxy_set_header        Host subdomain.domain.com;  # Need these, otherwise it uses the IP that it resolves to.
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For subdomain.domain.com;
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-Uri $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header        Orig-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Cookie $http_cookie;

}
```

I tried adding a number of the items above, but in the error log I keep seeing.

subrequest: "/auth", upstream: "https://192.168.0.100:443/ProxyPassAuth.php"

Where the IP is what the subdomain.domain.com resolves to (my local hosts file), rather than the hostname.  I need it to be a hostname so that the correct webdirectory with the ProxyPassAuth.php file gets loaded.  If I just put that page in the "default" location block directory, then that will work, but not an ideal solution.

Is there are way to force the upstream request to have a hostname rather than an IP address ?

There is some basic info here:  [Authentication Based on Subrequest Result](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/)

I should say that for the upstream request I really would prefer that that be made "within" the container.  In my Docker compose I have:

```
nginx:
    build: php-fpm-nginx
    depends_on: [pacs-1,mysql_db]
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: ["443:443"]
    volumes:
       - ./nginx-home:/nginx-home      # NGINX web directories
       - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx   # NGINX log directory
       - ./tls:/etc/nginx/tls          # NGINX ssl certs path
       - ./php-fpm-nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  # NGINX .conf
```

and then also several server blocks within the nginx.conf.

When I inspect the docker network I get:

```
"Containers": {

            "625c767be7903877794877790e3ca9e0f7fd12a5ee82f0c980ac7535300544f4": {
                "Name": "orthanc_docker_ris_nginx_1",
                "EndpointID": "6662e791069367b15885145ca16cc63f2bbdc8d6063fde406b42e3c7b359cab8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
            . . . .
            . . . .

        },
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Did you happen to get this resolved?

Comment: @JustinVogt  Not sure, but I think you might be able to put:  extra_hosts:  in the docker-compose.yml file to resolve the domain to an IP.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076194/using-add-host-or-extra-hosts-with-docker-compose.  For me, I could just use 127.0.0.1.